# Trying to Initialize a arraylist in java with another classes constructor

Tags: java, arraylist

So i'm trying to write an aggregate class of card and make it give the player a card or the computer but I need to "Initialize Hand" which I can't seem to figure out.

```
// 2 arg const 
public Card(String suit, int rank)
{
    this.suit = suit;
    this.rank = rank;
}
```

Above is the 2 argument constructor for the card class

```
private String name;
private ArrayList<Card> hand = new ArrayList<Card>();

// computer constructor
public Player()
{
    name = "Computer";
    hand.add(1, null);
}

// actual player constructor
public Player(String name)
{
    this.name = name;
    // This is where the hand initialization goes.
}
```

Comment: The argument `1` in `hand.add(1, null);` is pretty much unnecessary by the way, because the call `hand.add(null);` will supply an index by itself. In this context the index doesn't seem to matter (you shouldn't use an `ArrayList` if you want to keep the order anyway :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to do `hand.add(new Card("hearts",10))`, for example. Do that for each card in the hand.

Comment: Okay so that makes sense but if I have getters and setters should I just use the getters instead? Like such `hand.add(new Card(getSuit(), getRank()));`

Comment: @MemeLord, yes, you can certainly use getters instead (if, of course, they return the same types)

Comment: Where are these getters and setters? Which class are they a member of?

Comment: They are in the card class and the data types in there a private.

Comment: Then no, you can't use them how you are trying to. First, in your example, you are trying to call them as if they are methods of the Player class, which they aren't. Second, they aren't static methods, so you need to create a card object first before using them.

Comment: I'm aware of both of those don't worry. I figured it out

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be ok if you just passed the ArrayList as a parameter and set your instance variable equal to it. Because it's a pointer reference, it would refer to the same ArrayList.

Another thing is you could create a new ArrayList and add all the cards from the hand parameter like forgivenson said, and in the past I've done both  and both have worked.

Another thing is you might need to import Card if it's not in the same package (I could be wrong with this though, correct me if I am). But I'm assuming Player and Card would go into the same package.